# I am runnin VB6.0 and cannot get a recordet to return daya

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-express

I am trying to raise the following recordset in sql server.
I  am using the following sql statement. The date format on the server is 2022-03-2022 10-00;00:00

SQL is
SELECT * FROM mutable
Where date = '2022-03-07'

It returns 0 records

What is the problem?

Comment: `2022-03-2022 10-00;00:00` isn't a valid date and time value. What is the `10-00;00:00` meant to even represent here? What "date" is `2022-03-2022`? March has 31 days, not over 2000.

Comment: And why are you runnin VB6.0?

Comment: if date is a datetime column, then you'll only get records if the times match exactly as well.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft because Microsoft won't let it just die. Whilst the VisualBasic 6.0 IDE became unsupported in 2008 the runtimes are still supported on Windows Server 2008 R2 all the way through to Windows 11. [Support Statement for Visual Basic 6.0 on Windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-basic-6/visual-basic-6-support-policy)

Comment: You can still run 16-bit DOS applications; that doesn't mean you should write them.

Comment: Thank you all. I am 68, and older than vb6.0. Therefore for the sake of a one-off exercise that is why I am using it. I can still use the IDE reasonably. Bt dates were defeating me. I have now resolved my bad syntax on date selection. Apologies for bad spelling in places and the example I gave!